# Distribution Type after new observations

Tags: distributions

We have this pdf for $x_1, x_2,\dotsc, x_n$ :
$$\theta x^{\theta -1 }$$ with indicator variable 1 for $ 0 \le x \le 1$.

We decide not to observe the $x_1,x_2,\dotsc,x_n$ but $y_1,y_2,\dotsc,y_n$ where $y_i = \text{Indicator Variable(1)}$ for $x_i \le 0.5$. We need to estimate $\theta $ based on new data. What is the distribution of $Y_i$?

I am bit confused, but I am supposing that $Y_i$ is a Bernoulli distribution ? Am I on the right path?

In fact the question is simple is to choose whether Y is a Bernoulli, Normal, Poisson or Exponential Distribution ...

Comment: To start: Find $p = P(X \le .5) = \int_0^{.5} \theta x^{\theta - 1}\,dx.$ Then $Y \sim \mathsf{Bern}(p).$ The statement of the problem seems to be missing restrictions on possible values of $\theta.$

Comment: which gives $0.5^{\theta}$

Comment: The restriction on theta is ${\theta>0}$

Comment: @Sitingbull: Can you please add new information as an edit to the original Q? That way more people will see it.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain a *maximum likelihood* (ML) estimate for $\theta$ by maximizing $P(\mathbf{y}|\theta)=\prod_{i=1}^n p(y_i|\theta)$. As you and @BruceET said, $Y_i$ is Bernoulli RV with $p=0.5^\theta$. Bernoulli RV has PDF/PMF $p(y|p)=p^y(1-p)^{1-y}$. In your case it is $p(y_i|\theta)=0.5^{\theta y_i}(1-0.5^\theta)^{1-y_i}$, which yields the following likelihood:
$$P(\mathbf{y}|\theta)=0.5^{\theta \sum y_i}(1-0.5^\theta)^{n-\sum y_i}$$
ML estimation of $\theta$ maximizes this likelihood. One way to find it is to differentiate it (or logarithm of it since it is in general algebraically easier) wrt $\theta$ (let $\sum y_i = S$):
$$\begin{align}\frac{d}{d\theta}\log P(\mathbf{y}|\theta)&= \frac{d}{d\theta}\left(\theta S\log 0.5+(n-S)\log(1-0.5^\theta)\right)\\ &= S\log 0.5-(n-S)\frac{0.5^\theta \log 0.5}{1-0.5^\theta}=0\end{align}$$
This yields $$\frac{S}{n-S}=\frac{0.5^\theta}{1-0.5^\theta}\rightarrow\hat{\theta} =  \frac{\log (S/n)}{\log 0.5}$$

By the way, all of these computations could have been avoided by knowing the ML estimation of $p$ yields $S/n$ beforehand, and letting $0.5^\theta=S/n$.

And, I assumed you don't want a MAP estimation since you treat $\theta$ an unknown fixed number instead of a random variable with some prior PDF.

Comment: I dont seem to understand your differentiation of the second part $$(n-S)log(1-0.5^{\theta})$$ especially the numerator, as differentiating it, will give something like $$ - \theta0.5^{\theta-1}$$, which will be in the numerator. I don't see( i can be wrong) how the log is being conserved after differentiation,

Comment: $a^x$ has derivative wrt $x$ as $a^x \log a$.