# Method of Moments Bernoulli

Tags: self-study, distributions, method-of-moments

We have this pdf for $x_1, x_2,\dotsc, x_n$ :
$$\theta x^{\theta -1 }$$ with indicator variable 1 for $ 0 \le x \le 1$.

We decide not to observe the $x_1,x_2,\dotsc,x_n$ but $y_1,y_2,\dotsc,y_n$ where $y_i = \text{Indicator Variable(1)}$ for $x_i \le 0.5$. We need to estimate $\theta $ based on new data.

I concluded after some help that Y is a bernoulli distribution with p = $0.5^{\theta}$ with a pdf of $0.5^{\theta y_i}(1-0.5^\theta)^{1-y_i}$.

I need to calculate the method of moment for the estimator $\hat{\theta}$ for $ \theta$.

I started with calculating $E(X)$ by integrating $ \int \theta x^{\theta -1 } $ over 0.5 to 0, this yielded to $\frac{\theta}{\theta +1}0.5^{\theta+1}$ which I equated to $\bar{Y}$ but I have the impression my result wont be good as isolating $\theta$ is pretty challenging...

Can you please tell me if my way of thought is correct?

Comment: related to this thread : https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/401467/distribution-type-after-new-observations

Comment: If this is some homework, please add the 'self-study' tag.

Answer (score 1):

You say you want to estimate $\theta$ by the method of moments based on new data. So where does $X$ come from in this algebra? Your new population is  $\mathsf{Ber}(0.5^\theta)$, not the original $\mathsf{Beta}(\theta,1)$.

The observed sample from the Bernoulli distribution is $Y_1,\ldots,Y_n$.

By method of moments, sample mean $\overline Y$ is equated to population mean $E(Y_1)=0.5^\theta$, from which you are to solve for $\theta$.